# FTP Server running but not able to upload files

Tags: ftp, ubuntu-16.04, vsftpd

I'm running an Ubuntu 16.04 instance on Google Compute Engine, with vsftpd installed. I have everything configured, user, password, directories etc, but when I try to login, I am able to login only via net2ftp.com. In chrome I just see a blank page after entering my credentials, in Windows explorer I get an error:

> An error occurred opening that folder on the FTP server. Make sure you have permission to access that folder.
>
> Details:
>
> 200 Switching to ASCII mode.
>
> 227 Entering Passive mode.

In FileZilla client, the status bar shows:

> Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.

and remains stuck there, and then times out.

Even in Net2FTP, I am able to just login, see the directory listing, and download files. Not able to upload anything. Whenever I try to upload anything I get a message

> Checking files: 
>   File xxxx.xxx is OK
>
> Transferring files to the FTP server: 
>   File xxxx.xxx could not be transferred to the FTP server

Here is my vsftpd.conf file:

> listen=NO
>
> listen_ipv6=YES
>
> anonymous_enable=NO
>
> local_enable=YES
>
> write_enable=YES
>
> dirmessage_enable=YES
>
> use_localtime=YES
>
> xferlog_enable=YES
>
> connect_from_port_20=YES
>
> ascii_upload_enable=YES
>
> ascii_download_enable=YES
>
> chroot_local_user=YES
>
> secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
>
> pam_service_name=vsftpd

Comment: Did you try to google your question? This has been asked like zillion times already!

Comment: I did, before posting the question here... I was unable to find the exact solution for my problem

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need to configure your passive mode ports and open them on your firewall.

Read here for starters: https://serverfault.com/questions/421161/how-to-configure-vsftpd-to-work-with-passive-mode

Comment: This partially solved the problem. I am now able to view directory listing from FileZilla and Chrome, but I am still getting the same error in Windows Explorer, and I am still unable to upload any file via any client.